# How to configure pylint with pycharm on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm, pylint

Below python can be executed as `python test.py --abcd=value`

**test.py**

```
from optparse import OptionParser

class Test(object):
   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def _test1(self, some_val):
      print(some_val)

   def main(self, some_val):
      self.test1(some_val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   parser = OptionParser()
   parser.add_option("-a", "--abcd", dest="abcd", default=None,
                      help="some_val")

   (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
   some_val = options.abcd

   mainobj = Test()
   mainobj.main(some_val)
```

I would like to be more align with python coding standards (though aware of PEP8 and other stuffs).

```
How can I integrate pylint with pycharm ?
```

What are `Program, Arguments & Working directory`  in Tool settings `(File > Tool > External Tools > linters/External Tool > Tool Settings)` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the easy option is to run pylint using Pycharm's terminal, which supposes to work with your current environment by default (at least).

Pylint can also be installed as Pycharm's plugin.

Full information to integrate Pylint with Pycharm in [this](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/ide-integration.html#pylint-in-pycharm) link.

To add Pylint as Pycharm's plugin:

1. Open 'Settings' using  `Ctrl + Alt + s` or just `file->Settings...`
2. search for: plugins
3. in plugins: search for: Pylint wor
4. download/enable
5. press okay and restart PyCharm
6. a new tab with Pythons icon should appear at the bottom screen saying "Pylint". Done.

if pycharm can't detect Pylint executable enter it manually at:

```
Preferences > Settings > Pylint -> Path to Pylint exectuable
```

and use the "Test" button to check it actually works.

info about PEP8 [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)